# Could not load folder contents - SSRS Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

What I want to do is log into report server manager. I have added the user to a job role in SSMS and have equally assigned the user to a specific role in Report Manager (2016). Through a secure host, I can log in with the built-in account but I am unable to log in using the created user account. The error returned is:

```
  Could not load folder contents
  You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions.
```

How do I resolve  this issue?

Comment: Refer to my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322333/230585

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this same issue and had to adjust the permissions on SSRS at the "home" root folder on 2016

Comment: Can you explain us, Where did you change the permission and how?

Comment: See the answer below (from Ruud), does that help .  Change it via the SQL SRS page.

Answer (score 34):

To eleborate on STGdb his answer. The settings on the home folder can be found at 'Manage Folder':[image]

Comment: When I try to load this page I have the message "Could not load folder contents 
You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions"

Answer (score 3):

Just as an addendum to @gwasshoppa's post (now that IE is retired): I installed Report Server locally just to test features and ran into the same issue. The way I solved it was to create a local Windows admin account on my machine (Settings->Other Users->Add Someone else to this PC, create the account, and then Change Account Type-> Administrator). Then, in a brand new browser window (had to use a different browser even), I logged into the Report Server URL and finally saw "Manage folder". Yes, finally! I clicked Manage folder, then added my normal Windows user (which is an admin on my machine) as a Content Manager and clicked Apply. Then I reloaded the Report Server web URL and voila! I can now see everything. I hope this helps you as much as it helped me.

Comment: By normal windows user you mean different from the created one? If it was already admin, as you say, then why create new admin user?

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error message:

> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions.

Make sure that the current account or Active Directory group is a member of the Local Administrator Group on the SSRS Server

Login to the SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Service ) Server.

**Open Server Manager > Tools > Computer Management.**

---

[image: screenshot]

[Reference](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/04/19/ssrs-2016-you-are-not-allowed-to-view-this-folder-contact-your-administrator-to-obtain-the-necessary-permissions/)

Comment: could you elaborate on "Login to the SSRS Server", what are exact steps to do it?

Comment: This worked for me also, thank you! I'd granted my domain account the "System Administrator" role from the SSRS portal > Home > Site Settings, and I could log in, but then got the message about not having permissions to view the folder contents. I also couldn't deploy reports from Visual Studio. Added my domain account to the local administrators group and bam, it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
***The solution is:***
1- **Browse** the Report Manager URL
2- Top right of the page/ **Manage folder**/ **Add group or user**
3- An important point is that in **Group or user**, you have to insert the name which has been added before in SQL Server Report. You cannot insert your favorable name. It is the point that took me time a lot. 
4- After inserting the name, choose the **Browser role** for that particular name.
5- Go to **Home**/ **Your Project**/ **Right click**/ **Manage**, then **Security**, go to Add **group or user**
6- Do the same as before for this step.
7- Your problem will be solved

Alireza Azad

Comment: This is a a direct copy/paste from the internet - at least give some credit to the original writer. Also, how is this different from Ruud's answer? Did you even go through all the answers?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with Power BI report server (developer version) which I just setup in my local laptop to test, but None of the above solution worked for me.

**Problem:**
actually I have a domain user added as an admin and also another local admin user. All the installation etc. was done using domain admin user only.
But at the end this domain user was not having permission to change site setting in portal and also it was getting logged in automatically with domain user every time I browse http://localhost/reports

**solution:**
Opened a incognito window browse http://localhost/reports and this time it asked for username/password so I provided the local admin credentials and that worked. Now I am able to access the site settings and added my domain account in security tab.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting frustrated with this, but it was simple. I did not add myself under the folder settings. Got this from Power BI Forms

*Please launch browser with administrator role. And check whether current account has been granted with access permission on both System level security (under site setting) and Item level security (under Manager Folder).*

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Power-BI-Report-Server-You-are-not-allowed-to-view-this-folder/td-p/236338

Answer (score 1):

If you are an administrator, login to the report server locally at `http://localhost/Reports/browse/`. You should see a Manage Folder button. Click that.

As an admin, I only could only see the Manage Folder button while on localhost. I had to specifically add my local user account before I could access the report server from another machine (despite the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group having "Content Manager" permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions issue. Check that you have granted the user account item level permissions to view the specific folder you are trying to access. To do this, browse to the folder the reports reside in with the built-in account, click on manage, click on the security tab and grant the user the necessary permissions so that they may view the contents of the folder.

Also try to access it using Internet explorer to test Windows Authentication. The user may not currently be authenticated.

To dig deeper, you can also view the logs to see the exact permissions issue. The error log is usually located in a similar location to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles\
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to:

1. Verify both the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases have been restored correctly.
2. Make sure to restore the Encryption Key from the Reporting Services configuration tool.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was not even able to get "Manage folder" displayed in the page until i added the site in trusted sites list

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above thing won't work for you and you dont want to rebuild your SSRS services again. Just simply recreate your reportserverDB and rebuild it via reportserver configuration manager tool.

Note : please make sure  you having report .rdl backup's with you handy

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a Microsoft Azure AD or Office 365 login to log onto their local machine and you are setting up Reporting Services on your PC, you need to do the following.

1. Find out your PC logged in user name. To do this on your PC click the Windows
   Icon > Type in "Other Users".
2. This will display a list of users on this PC. You need your user
   name. It will be in the form "AzureAD\MyUserName"

[image]

3. Open Internet Explorer (As Administrator).
4. Browse to your localhost report server. it will be either http://localhost/reports or https://localhost/reports depending on whether you have set up SSL.
5. Click the "Settings" Icon top right of the page.

   [image]
6. Click the "+ Add group or user" button, and enter your AzureAD\MyUserName.
7. Tick the "Content Manager" check box and click OK. This will add your AzureAD user to the "Site Settings" as a Content Manager.
8. Next we need to add your user as a Content Manager to "Manager Folder". To do this click the red icon top left to go to the "Home" folder.
   [image]
9. Click the "Manage folder" button on the right top of the screen.
   [image]
10. Repeat item 6. and 7. on this screen, and this will add your AzureAD user to the Folders as a "Content Manager".
11. You should now be able to access the http://localhost/reports using any browser without running it as administrator.